# restrict acess openfire Jabber

Tags: linux

It would be very helpful for me to know how can I restrict access only to PC/Laptop?  That is  no one should able to connect to jabber from any other mobile devices. I am using Linux.

Answer (score 0):

An XMPP client on a PC is not different in any practical way from an XMPP client on a mobile device, but if they're on a different network (wireless vs wired), or the problem is access from a different location (over the internet?), then you may have options.  You haven't provided enough detail to assist with that.

Depending on whether your PC XMPP clients are standardized, one option may be to use OpenFire's Client Control plugin, which restricts which client applications are allowed to connect.  See [here](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/clientcontrol/readme.html).

Comment: Can you please let me know how this can be achieved using OpenFire's Client Control plugin.

Comment: @user127138 Well, first you need to determine if it's appropriate.  Is every single user running the same client software on their PC?

Comment: Yes they are using pidgin.

Comment: Then install the Client Control plugin from within the OpenFire Manager's plugin section, set it to only allow specified clients, and select just Pidgin.